# How to get the network state either phone is connected to internet or not ?

Tags: android, network-programming, android-sdk-tools

How to get the network state either phone is connected to internet(wifi or Mobile internet) or not ? i using the below code but when i am disconnecting from WIFI it still returning the true. don't know what is the problem here!! please suggest what to do .

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
            //we are connected to a network
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
```

I put the permission in manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Comment: Look at it: https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html

Answer (score 0):

You should create a broadcast receiver to monitor conectivity changes:

```
<action android:name="android.net.conn.CONNECTIVITY_CHANGE"/>
```

[Docs](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/connectivity-monitoring.html#MonitorChanges)

[Broadcast Receiver example](http://www.androhub.com/android-detect-internet-connection-using-broadcast-receiver/)

[Brodcast Receiver example 2](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/)

Comment: @hiteshchauhan My bad, its not a permission as you said, it's a broadcast receiver. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [getType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/NetworkInfo.html#getType()) from ConnectivityManager class

```
private int getConnectionType(Context context){
    ConnectivityManager cm =  (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    return activeNetwork.getType();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Code is absolutely Right because i was testing it on Emulator . but when i tested this on my device it runs perfectly

```
private boolean isNetworkAvailable() {
    ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager)getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo netInfo = connectivityManager.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnected()) {
        //we are connected to a network
        return true;
    }
    else
        return false;
}
```